# Configure bonded 802.3ad network using netplan on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking

I am running into some issues configuring netplan on Ubuntu 18.04 server to bond my four hardware ethernet ports named `eno1, eno2, eno3, eno4` using the 802.3ad protocol. I've consulted the netplan [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man5/netplan.5.html) and put together the following config file `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml`:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eports:
      match: 
        name: eno*
  bonds:
    bond0:
      interfaces: [eports]
      addresses: [192.168.1.101/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]          
      parameters:
        mode: 802.3ad            
        lacp-rate: fast            
        mii-monitor-interval: 100
```

Upon running the command `sudo netplan --debug apply` I receive the following information:

```
** (generate:6473): DEBUG: 00:39:14.911: Processing input file //etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml..
** (generate:6473): DEBUG: 00:39:14.911: starting new processing pass
** (generate:6473): DEBUG: 00:39:14.911: eports: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:6473): DEBUG: 00:39:14.911: bond0: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:6473): DEBUG: 00:39:14.912: Generating output files..
** (generate:6473): DEBUG: 00:39:14.912: NetworkManager: definition eports is not for us (backend 1)
** (generate:6473): DEBUG: 00:39:14.912: NetworkManager: definition bond0 is not for us (backend 1)
DEBUG:netplan generated networkd configuration exists, restarting networkd
DEBUG:no netplan generated NM configuration exists
DEBUG:device eno2 operstate is up, not replugging
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for eno2
DEBUG:device lo operstate is unknown, not replugging
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for lo
DEBUG:replug eno3: unbinding 0000:03:00.0 from /sys/bus/pci/drivers/igb
DEBUG:replug eno3: rebinding 0000:03:00.0 to /sys/bus/pci/drivers/igb
DEBUG:replug eno1: unbinding 0000:01:00.0 from /sys/bus/pci/drivers/igb
DEBUG:replug eno1: rebinding 0000:01:00.0 to /sys/bus/pci/drivers/igb
DEBUG:Cannot replug bond0: cannot read link /sys/class/net/bond0/device: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/sys/class/net/bond0/device'
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for bond0
DEBUG:replug eno4: unbinding 0000:04:00.0 from /sys/bus/pci/drivers/igb
DEBUG:replug eno4: rebinding 0000:04:00.0 to /sys/bus/pci/drivers/igb
```

I'm not sure what to make of the statement

```
Cannot replug bond0: cannot read link /sys/class/net/bond0/device: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/sys/class/net/bond0/device'
```

since the directory `/sys/class/net/bond0` was generated by the `netplan apply` command.

I checked my `ifconfig` output and my network devices seem to be configured correctly with the exception that no address is set for `bond0`:

```
bond0: flags=5123<UP,BROADCAST,MASTER,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 112768  bytes 7785014 (7.7 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 54  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 18854  bytes 2337896 (2.3 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eno1: flags=6211<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SLAVE,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 290  bytes 19322 (19.3 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 55  bytes 6820 (6.8 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    device memory 0xdf400000-df47ffff  

eno2: flags=6211<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SLAVE,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 73991  bytes 29824155 (29.8 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 20848  bytes 2110417 (2.1 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    device memory 0xdf300000-df37ffff  

eno3: flags=6147<UP,BROADCAST,SLAVE,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    device memory 0xdf200000-df27ffff  

eno4: flags=6147<UP,BROADCAST,SLAVE,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    device memory 0xdf100000-df17ffff  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 2923  bytes 184477 (184.4 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 2923  bytes 184477 (184.4 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

The `ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX` statements are in place of each interfaces's mac address. In the original output, all addresses are the same.

What am I missing to successfully configure my system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging, I discovered that Ubuntu 18.04 uses a utility called `cloud-init` to handle network configuration and initialization during the boot sequence. The file `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/50-curtin-networking.cfg` and other `.cfg` files are used to reconfigure `cloud-init` settings. My config file settings are as follows:

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    eports:
      match:
        name: eno*
      optional: true
  bonds:
    bond0:
      interfaces: [eports]
      addresses: [192.168.1.101/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
      parameters:
        mode: 802.3ad
        lacp-rate: fast
        mii-monitor-interval: 100
```

The `optional: true` parameter prevents the system from waiting for a valid network connection at boot time which will save you the hassle of waiting 2 minutes for your machine to boot. After updating the config file run the following command to update your configuration.

```
cloud-init clean -reboot
```

Alternatively running the following allows for some debug information without rebooting your machine; however, a reboot will be required to commit the changes during early boot stages.

```
cloud-init clean
cloud-init init
cloud-init status
```